# Polymer 2.x - how to make this search-filter work?

Tags: polymer, custom-component, polymer-2.x, custom-element

I want to implement a search-filter for elements in a Polymer 2.x web app. 

I have this code from Polymer 1.x down below and I'm not sure how to make it work in Polymer 2.x

How do I make the code from Polymer 1.x below, to work on this Polymer 2.x page:

#### my-home.html | script area

```
  <script>
    class Myhome extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() { return 'my-home'; }
    }

    window.customElements.define(Myhome.is, Myhome);
  </script>
```

### The search filter code from Polymer 1.x:

#### html

```
 <div class="app-grid" style="display: flex;">
    <template items="[[data]]">
      <div class="item horizontal wrap layout" style="width: 300px; height: 300px; margin: 2%;">
        <paper-card heading="[[item.title]]" image="http://lorempixel.com/300/200">
           <div class="card-content">[[item.description]]</div>
           <div class="card-actions">
             <paper-button>Button</paper-button>
           </div>
        </paper-card>
      </div>
    </template>
  </div>
```

#### script

```
<script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'my-home',
      properties:{
          defaultData:{
            type:Array,
            value:[{title:'Color picture',description:'An RGB picture'},
              {title:'Grey image',description:'That\'s a grey picture'},
              {title:'3',description:'this is content 3'}]
          },
          data:{
            type:Array
          }
        },
        ready:function(){
          this.data = this.defaultData;
          this.$.search.addEventListener('keyup',this.searchChanged.bind(this));
        },
        searchChanged:function(e){
          var querySearch = this.$.search.value.toLowerCase();
          if(querySearch == ''){
            this.data = this.defaultData;
          }else{
            this.data = this.defaultData.filter(function(item){
              return item.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(querySearch) !== -1 || item.description.toLowerCase().indexOf(querySearch)  !== -1;
            });
          }
        }
    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

A lot of your script will have to change, perhaps most notably by upgrading to a class-based element. [See the relevant section in the Polymer upgrade guide.](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/upgrade#upgrading-to-class-based-elements) This will include [adding a call to `super.ready()`](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/upgrade#ready-time) as the first line of your `ready()` function

Comment: Thanks. It's just, Polymer is so confusing....as a newbie developer it's hard to even begin understanding it, because there aren't any good tutorials showing the whole process of building and implementing different components in a project. I think I'm gonna go with Vue.js instead.

Comment: Oh, I personally disagree and found Polymer to be a far better onboarding experience for our team than any other framework I've used, especially because the paper-elements do soooo much for you.

Comment: Well, I like it as well, it's just so hard to understand it on a deeper level. How do you guys all learn it anyways? Do you just have a good web-developer background and just use documentation to understand how the framework works?

Comment: I recommend checking out the polymer-starter-kit (https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit), shop tutorial app (https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/toolbox/case-study), and news tutorial app (https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/toolbox/news-case-study) if you want to learn more!!

Comment: Thanks for the links, I'll check it out now

Comment: When I was first learning I did not have a strong webdev background - I mostly got along by just ignoring all the stuff about the shadow DOM, etc., and focused on just leveraging existing components as much as possible, so that really the only JavaScript code I was writing was 1-2 line observer functions.

Comment: Also try the stuff on the main page - https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/start/first-element/intro through the "build an app" section.

Of course, if it's not for you it's not for you. Best of luck!